# what diagram to use for task communication

Tags: multithreading, oop, uml

In a class we use Concurrency Diagrams (of the type shown here http://www.modelmakertools.com/modelmaker/screenshots/concurrency-diagram.html) to visualise the tasks in a system and the communication and synchronisation mechanisms (flags, semaphores, queues, mailboxes, timers, ...) used by and between the tasks. We want to get rid of the tool we used to draw such diagrams (Artisan), but almost none of the other tools seem to support this kind of diagram.

- Can anyone suggest a (preferrably free and lightweight) tool to draw such diagrams?
- Alternatively, what diagrams do you use to express the communication and synchronision between tasks? (and what tool do you use to draw those?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UML [Activity Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram) to visualize concurrency.
There are many tools available to create UML diagrams, you can find the list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

I can recommend http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/activity/draw as a nice and lightweight option.

Comment: AD's do visualise concurrency, but do not explicitly show taks or concurrency (communication and synchronisation) mechanisms. We do use AD's, but erlier in the process, to formalize use cases.